# AS3: ISO8601 convert date/time

Tags: actionscript-3

My code:

```
var util:ISO8601Util = new ISO8601Util();

var date:Date = util.parseDateTimeString("2014-08-01T10:36:19+08:00");
var currentdate:Date = new Date();

var extended:String = util.formatExtendedDateTime( currentdate )
var basic:String = util.formatBasicDateTime( currentdate );
trace("currentdate:" + currentdate);
trace("=============================");
trace("Extended: "+extended);
```

my code for parseDateTimeString:

```
 public function parseDateTimeString( val:String ):Date
        {
            //first strip all non-numerals from the String ( convert all extended dates to basic)
            val = val.replace( /-|:|T|Z/g, "" );

            var date:Date = parseBasicDate( val.substr( 0, 8 ) );
            date = parseBasicTime( val.substr( 8, 6 ), date );

            return date;
        }
```

Output:

```
   currentdate:Wed Aug 27 15:00:02 GMT+0800 2014
=============================
Extended: 2014-08-27T07:00:02Z
```

AS you see, the time for the currentdate is 15:00:02: [3:00PM] but then when i tried to convert it in tru extended ISO8601 the output 06:48:42 [7:00AM]

Why the output for the extended ISO8601 is wrong?

Please help me..

I just get the code here..

http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2009/02/23/convert-an-iso-8601-date-string-to-from-a-native-as3-date-object/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the method parseW3CDTF from [com.adobe.utils.DateUtil](https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/utils/DateUtil.as)?

Comment: For anybody reading this in the future, this is the correct answer.
`DateUtil.parseW3CDTF(str)` works.